# jQuery animate prevent all boxes sliding up together

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate, slide

I have 36 boxes where you hover over the title and it slides up to show the hidden text below it, whilst it works as expected the problem is all 36 boxes slide up at the same time instead of just the one you moused over here is the script I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.caption').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.caption').stop().animate({height: "60%"});
    }); 

    $('.box').mouseleave(function(){
        $('.caption').stop().animate({height: "8%"},  1000, function() {
        });
    });
});
```

Now after much reading I found that I need to use "this" so I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.caption').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.caption', this).stop().animate({height: "60%"});
    }); 

    $('.box').mouseleave(function(){
        $('.caption', this).stop().animate({height: "8%"},  1000, function() {
        });
    });
});
```

However that just disables the animation altogether, I tried using ".next" also and many other combinations that just resulted in the animation being disabled also.

In short, I have 36 boxes and I only want the actual one you mouse over to slide up not all of them at the same time.

I am a total jQuery novice and have searched for hours but cannot find a working example of exactly what I wish to achieve. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you also provide some of your html?

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle for your work?

Comment: Try taking the .caption out of your animate functions and just have the this object

Comment: Because the this object is a reference to the specific object that the event was called on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking the `.caption` out of your animate function and just use the reference to `this` like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.caption').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height: "60%"});
}); 

$('.box').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height: "8%"},  1000, function() {
    });
});
});
```

The `this` object when used with a jquery even is a reference to the specific element the event was called on.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply guys... @Binvention using the above yes now only one box slides up at a time however when it slides up now the title stays at the top of the container and when you mosueover again the text below will side up instead.... I will try and do a fiddle to show what I am talking about.

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you're meaning what problem are you having?

Answer (score 0):

Ah I got it !

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.caption').mouseenter(function(){
$(this).stop().animate({height: "60%"});
}); 

$('.caption').mouseleave(function(){
$(this).stop().animate({height: "8%"},  1000, function() {
});
});
});
```

Just changed .box to .caption and its working, Thank you guys for you help !
I am going to mark yours as correct though since your answer did put me in the right direction and I only had to make that small change.